# Level Order traversal Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I a m trying a simple level order traversal of a Binary tree,but it says I am having an segfault.I am putting up the code for the function which I am using.

```
#include<queue>
/*
 struct node
{
int data;
node* left;
node* right;
}*/

void LevelOrder(node * root)
{

queue<node*> q;

q.push(root);


while(!q.empty())
{
    node* t;
    t=q.front();
    cout<<t->data;

    q.push(t->left);
    q.push(t->right);
    q.pop();

 }

 }
```

Comment: Are you using gcc? If yes please use gdb it would be good learning for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if `left` and `right` are null.

```
if (t->left) {
    q.push(t->left);
}
if (t->right) {
    q.push(t->right);
}
```

And if `root` can be null,  you also need to check it.